# FluentUI detailsList with groups - is there a way to prevent the group row from being selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, fluent-ui

i took a look at the fluent detailsList grouped example in the official page of fluentUI:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist/grouped

and edited their example a bit so some of the groups has 1 row

now when I select the item in the row the group row (the group title) is also selected
[image]

I want to prevent that. is there a way?

Answer (score 2):

A quick workaround would be doing it by CSS:

if an element has `ms-GroupHeader is-selected` classes, means it is a gruop header and also is selected, so you change set the background-color.

You probably can pass a className to group components like [this](https://codepen.io/c0m1t/pen/oNzyQwd)

Comment: thank you, we ended up doing:

   .is-selected.ms-GroupHeader{
       background: none!important;
   }
so if you want to edit your answer i'll accept it

Comment: @NoIdeaForName I did not say to use `ms-GroupHeader is-selected` as a css selector (I was not clear enough). What I meant was if an element has those two classes, which translates to `.is-selected.ms-GroupHeader` selector, is an element you want to override its styles. But be careful, using that selector will affect all of your group headers, so you may want to pass a custom class to have more control over what to be affected or not (As you see in codepen). Also you can probably avoid that `!important`. Glad it was helpful.